# Checking if a specific Wordpress user or no user is logged in conditional

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to construct a conditional statement that checks if a specific user or no user is logged in and displays specific output.

I have at the moment:

```
    <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>

    <?php if $current_user = 'PQ'() || if $current_user = ''(); ?>
    <span class="OrderNumber">#<?php echo types_render_field("user", array("raw"=>"true",)); ?>-<?php the_ID(); ?></span>
    <?php else ?>

    <span class="OrderNumber">#<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>-<?php the_ID(); ?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a built in function in WordPress. `is_user_logged_in()`

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //your code
} else {
    //please login
}
?>
```

additionally `wp_login_form();` will displays a simple login dialog